# Move up Validation in Configurable Product Page

Tags: magento2, addtocart, validation, form-validation, labels

Is it possible to move up label, below the fields? 
And where I can find it? I tried in validation.js, but didn't have much luck.

[image]

Comment: Already warning message are showing at correct place in my case. Did you changed anything before or you can check console errors

Comment: No, I didn't change anything. Other warnings are fine, but only this one is move down. Have no idea how to move it up, since it's all added via js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default this warning message comes from core module **Magento Swatches.**

```
vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js
```

Override core js file into your theme,

```
/app/design/frontend/{Packagename}}/{themename}}/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js
```

Replace

```
 if ($widget.productForm) {
    $widget.productForm.append(input);
    input = '';
}
```

with,

```
if ($widget.productForm) {
    $widget.productForm.find('#product-options-wrapper').after(input);
    input = '';
}
```

Comment: Thank youu, a lot!